# Topological Vector Space is separable if its dual space $X^*$ is separable?

Tags: topological-vector-spaces, separable-spaces

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a Topological Vector Space such that the associated dual space $X^*$ is separable. Can we say that $X$ is separable ?

I know that this property is valid for Banach spaces but for topological vector spaces, I have no idea.

An idea please.

Answer (score 3):

This can fail badly if $X$ is not locally convex.  Consider $X = L^p(\Omega,\mu)$ where $0 < p < 1$ and $\Omega = [0,1]^\Gamma$ where
$\Gamma$ is uncountable and $\mu$ is the product Lebesgue measure.  Then $X$ is non-separable, but $X^* = 0$.